# Approach for .NET Asynchronous Oracle Connectivity

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oracle, asynchronous

Whats the best practice for Asynchronous Oracle Connectivity in .NET specifically C#.  Ideally something that is compatible with Sqlserver Connectivity by way of a DbFactory Pattern.  As I must support both oracle and Sql Server.  Currently I am using the ADO.NET DbProviderFactory which does not support Async Calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a delegate for your db call methods which will give you the async functionality. Of course, I have no idea what implications this might have. You will need to test it out.

Using either SqlConnection or OracleConnection as the generic base type, you can create your generic repository (add, get, delete, etc)

public Row GetByID(int id) {}

delegate void GetByIDDelegate(int id);

var dbCall = new GetByIDDelegate(GetByID);

dbCall.BeginAsync(...);

This is just off the top of my head.